# Dynamically fetch associated entities

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa, fetch

I have 3 entities

Project.java

```
@Entity
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ProjectReview> projectReviews = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters
}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reviewer")
    private List<ProjectReview> projectReviews = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters
}
```

ProjectReview.java

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ProjectRevieweId.class)
public class ProjectReview {

    @Id
    private long projectId;

    @Id
    private long userId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String review;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User reviewer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "projectId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Project project;

    // getters
}
```

Pretty simple many-to-many relationship with join table. This setup is not working, because when serialized with jackson to json format, it has infinite depth **EVEN** if the default fetch type is `LAZY` on collections (i dont understand why!?).

I am using standard Spring `Repository->Service->RestController` flow with `Spring Boot 1.4.1` on `MySQL`.

I used the `@JsonBackReference` on `ProjectReview.reviewer` and `ProjectReview.project` but thats not what I want, because sometimes i want to have access to associated entities, and sometimes not. Explanation folllows:

When I call rest service GET ../projects, i would like to see

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "name":"project1",
    "projectReviews":[{
        "review":"My super review!",
        "reviewer":{ -- this has to be included
            "id":1,
            "userName":"user1",
            "projectReviews":null -- this cant be fetched as it causes recursion
            },
        "project":{ -- instance or null or entirely missing this attribute - as it is the same as root
            "id":1,
            "name":"project1",    
            "projectReviews":null -- this cant be fetched as it causes recursion        
            }
        },
        {
            -- second review...
        }]
    },{
            -- second project...
    },
    ...etc
]
```

But when I call GET ../users, i would like to see

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "userName":"user1",
    "projectReviews":[{
        "review":"My super review!",
        "reviewer":{ -- instance or null or entirely missing this attribute - as it is the same as root
            "id":1,
            "userName":"user1",
            "projectReviews":null -- this cant be fetched as it causes recursion
            },
        "project":{ -- this has to be included
            "id":1,
            "name":"project1",    
            "projectReviews":null -- this cant be fetched as it causes recursion        
            }       
        },
        {
            -- second review...       
        }]
    },{ 
        -- second user
    }
        ...etc
]
```

I hope you get it. `projectReviews` on top level should be eagerly fetched, but on second level they should not - beacuse it creates infinite depth structure.

How could I setup the fetching or entities to provide this king of structure?

Bonus question - Why are `projectReviews` fetched in json if default is `LAZY` fetching?

Comment: JSON does not support references **of any kind** - it should be obvious that without references a two-way relationship _is an_ infinite recursion. You simply cannot have a two-way relationship in JSON. Jackson can work around this with [some annotations](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) - you either have to remove one side of the relationship from the JSON or have a nonstandard (Jackson only) id reference.

Comment: You are trying to create JSON from a java object graph. That object graph supports references (a parent and child can mutually reference each other without problem). JSON does not support references - hence infinite recursion. If you don't mind Jackson-specific magic, I would go with `@JsonIdentityInfo`. Otherwise you are out of luck, and need to write manual logic...

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks I understand now, but I would like dynamicaly (programaticaly) control the fetching in differnet cases, isnt there a way? For example I think in cxf there were some fetchgroup capabilities on entity manager to specify what should be fetched. Is there a way to do something simliar with Spring repositories where I have no access to entity manager?

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks, i managed it with JsonViews annotation, please provide your useful link as answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use follwoing annotations to solve the infinite recursion problem : @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference.

Use @JsonManagedReference in User.java and Project.java for variable "projectReviews" and @JsonBackReference for "reviewer" and "project"

If you are not able to get reviewer and project under projectReviews, please use the annotations othey way around, @JsonManagedReference in projectReviews and vice versa.

Comment: thanks for response, but now inside the `projectReviews` I only see `review` but I dont see the `reviewer` or the `project`, please look on the response I posted in the question one more time, if you could update your answer.